# upgrade java from 1.5 to 1.6 on tomcat 5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, java-6, java-5

I want to upgrade java version to 1.6 from 1.5. but i want to keep my tomcat server intact that is to 5.5.9. I need to know what are the possible key areas where i might face issues after upgrading?  Or what should be the compatibility test criteria should be before doing anything on the server? I need to be aware of all the possible issues that i might face. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance..

my server details:
os: Red Hat Linux
jdk: 1.5.0_03
tomcat: 5.5.9
ram: 16 gb

Comment: Do a regression test for all your application deployed.

Comment: Quick question (out of interest): why upgrade the JVM but not the tomcat server? Tomcat 5.5.x has been EOL-ed since 2012. Or put differently: if you _must_ keep tomcat 5.5, why upgrade the JVM? :)

Comment: @nablex and the same applies to Java 6

Comment: Hi nablex and Andreas, thank you for your reply. Actually I am forced to upgrade java version because i am getting some issues which related to java native codes,therefore require upgrading.Actually i am afraid of doing this upgrade,because i am not a server architect,i haven't have enough knowledge.my java application is also written using a very old framework.So, i fear the more latest java or tomcat i will use, the more could be compatibility issue. Probably you guys can take my fear away :) thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Java_User, thanks for replying. Can you please provide me a link or something so that i can learn something on regression testing. Sorry for being naive.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing

Comment: @StephenC You may be aware that you helped me to find out jvm issue from looking at err_pid.log file in another thread. I just want to know will it be worth if i upgrade my java 1.5 to 1.6 ? and will that need a tomcat upgradation?my tomcat version is 5.5.9. i just want your expert advice.. thank you